# Difference Between sourceMapRootpath and sourceMapBasepath?

Tags: css, node.js, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

The grunt contrib less plugin has two similar sounding properties with similar descriptions.

```
sourceMapBasepath : Sets the base path for the less file paths in the source map.

sourceMapRootpath : Adds this path onto the less file paths in the source map.
```

To a layman these descriptions sound essentially the same. Could someone please contrast these two properties, possibly with a use case for each?

Comment: See [the docs](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-source-map-rootpath) for more detailed info.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thank you that is actually a very useful link!